# Where can I get windows 1.0 ISO file?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, iso-image

I am pretty curious to see and try out windows 1.0 as a virtual machine on my [VMware Workstation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation), but am unable to get its ISO file. Can anyone please suggest me a good place(except search engines, I didn't find ISO files anywhere) where I can download the ISO file?

The closest I got was [this](http://wdl2.winworldpc.com/Abandonware%20Operating%20Systems/PC/Microsoft%20Windows/Windows%201-2/), but this cannot be used to boot windows 1.0 as a VM.

Comment: @downvoters: Would be kind if you could leave a comment explaining what's wrong.

Comment: windows 1.0 was a 16-bit application released in 1985, not sure ISO is the way to go. Apparently it is still bootable as a VM though (not sure what hoops you'll have to jump through to make it work, but here is an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeIBoC5Xytk)

Answer (score 4):

You're probably not going to find it as an "ISO", seeing as it's <500KB zipped. :)

But you can get it from [WinWorld](http://winworldpc.com/library.shtml) in their software library.

[image]

"WinWorld is an online museum dedicated to the preservation and sharing of abandonware and pre-release software, as well as any and all knowledge associated with such works."

Can you trust this source? Dunno. ;)

Comment: Can you please explain how do a I boot a VM using this?

Comment: Use Floppy images.  First install DOS, then install Windows 1.   There are [a few YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=install+windows+1&sm=3) out there showing how.  Find one of those and follow it.  If you get stuck, come back and post a new question about that problem. :)